# Back to main view by button with navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

hi i have a class with navigation controller, in my main class i hide navigation bar with this code.
[self.navigationcontroller setnavigationbarHidden:YES];

i want to know, when i push to next.xib file, how can i go back to main by button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES]
```

Create a button and add an action to it

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then create the `back` method

```
-(void)back:(id)sender
{
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES]
```

If you want it using a button, add a button, and set its action handler to call that method.
e.g. you have

```
UIButton *backButton;
```

And set its action,

```
 [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didPressBackButton) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside
```

Then,

```
- (void) didPressBackButton {
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom buttoin and add the following code to its method call.

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];